# MVC 4 jQuery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there a way to get a jQuery modal dialog to be "truly" modal?

For example, if I create a confirmation dialog for a yes/no, how do I wait for the response from the user before processing anything else.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place your logic for after the dialog into the dialog's button events. You can't use it to pause execution of a method mid stream. Only the native javascript alert/confirm boxes can do that.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() { 
            // do whatever you want on OK.
        }
    }
] });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/